# Though external ip is resolved, the website returns connection timedout in kubernetes GKE

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a k8s deployment and service yaml for a static website. External IP address is also resolved in kubernetes service. But when I try to access the website through curl or browser, it returns connection timed out.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

K8s deployment yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ohno-website
  labels: 
          app: ohno-website
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
          matchLabels:
                  app: ohno-website
  template:
          metadata:
                      labels:
                              app: ohno-website
          spec:
                  containers:
                          - name: ohno-website
                            image: gkganeshr/ohno-website:v0.1
                            imagePullPolicy: Always
                            ports:
                                    - containerPort: 80
```

```
k8s service yml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ohno-website
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
          - protocol: TCP
            port: 80
            targetPort: 9376
  selector:
    app: ohno-website
```

```
ohno_fooserver@cloudshell:~ (fourth-webbing-279817)$ kubectl get svc
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes     ClusterIP      10.16.0.1      <none>          443/TCP        8h
ohno-website   LoadBalancer   10.16.12.162   34.70.213.174   80:31977/TCP   7h4m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target port defined in the service defition YAML is incorrect. It should match with container port from pod definition in deployment YAML

```
targetPort: 9376

should be changed to

targetPort: 80
```